# How can I update my Slack status in all of my workspaces?

Tags: macos, ios, slack

I am currently active in 7 different Slack workspaces. Whenever I want my status to be changed (e.g., coming online in the morning, going out for lunch, going offline in the evening), I manually have to go to every workspace and change the status there. This is of course very tedious and annoying as I have to do it every day.

Is there a smarter / more efficient way? Like ideally one global status update button or something like that...

If it matters, I am mostly using the MacOS desktop app of Slack, but would consider using the mobile iOS app or any other way for this.